# Does mongoose.connect create a Mongo database by default if it doesn't exist?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

In my Mongoose script I write:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydb');
```

But currently there is no `mydb` database in Mongo.  Will this create `mydb`if it doesn't already exist?

Comment: What happened when you tried it? This seems **easily** testable.

Comment: It created new database if there is no database exists.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The command `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydb');` will indeed create the database `mydb` if it does not exist.

It will also create any collections you use in your app if they do not already exist in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 3):

Upon doing dome experiment i found,

It created new database if there is no database exists